# How to make one of the nested components sticky in ScrollView?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have a component like this

```
<ScrollView>
 <View>
  <View>
   make this component sticky
  </View>
 </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Now, I want to make the second view sticky. I know ScrollView has a prop stickyHeaderIndices where you can specify the index but it won't work in my case as my concerned component is a nested one.